# how to print the names of tables of database using perl scripting using unix

Tags: perl

How to print the names of tables of database using Perl scripting using unix. Connected to DB using DBI module.

I tried scripting using

```
     my $driver= "Oracle";
     my $dsn = "DBI:$driver:sid=as;host=asdsa";
     my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, "a", "b") || die( $DBI::errstr . "\n" );
     my $notables = $dbh->tables();
     print "No of tables : $notables" ;
```

Getting error:

> Can't call method "tables" on an undefined value at hello.pl line 16.

Please help.

Comment: Your `$dbh` object is undefined. Are you sure you connected to the database? Pleae [edit] your question and include the part that does `my $dbh = DBI->connect`. Or better, include the full program. Also take a look at [ask] to learn how to format code in your question.

Comment: yes connected to db  .. updated the code.

Comment: Is this really the code that produces this error? It seems unlikely to me. A call to `connect()` will return either a database handle or `undef`. Returning `undef` would trigger your `die()` call, so you must be getting a defined database handle back from `connect()`. I suspect there is something else going in parts of the code that you have removed to simplify your example.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you not connected to DB.

Read [DBI](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#tables) documentation and try something like this:

```
use DBI;
use Data::Dumper;

my $dbh = DBI->connect($data_source, $username, $password)
          or die $DBI::errstr;

my @names = $dbh->tables( $catalog, $schema, $table, $type );
print Dumper @names;
```

$dbh->tables; without args is deprecated